# Why my fcntl function doesn't set the flag?

Tags: c, linux, fork

[my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvyaw.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvyaw.png)
After running my program waiting till there will be a symbol to read, but I want to end the program  when the read function cannot read anything

Id tried to set the flag inside the open function and it worked, but my exercise is to set the flag by the fcntl func

Comment: [Don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Please [edit] your question to copy-paste the code *as text*.

Comment: Regarding the code itself, *always* check for errors. All the functions you use could fail, but you will never notice.

Comment: `open(...., O_RDONLY)` itself is blocking so `fcnt()` isn't even executed before there is something to be read

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

First, you should read the current flags and update it like:

```
int flags = fcntl (a, F_GETFL, 0);
if (flags == -1) {
    // handle error
}
flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
fcntl (a, F_SETFL, flags);
```

Comment: it didn't work.